# How to add div elements inside WP menu?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have problems to convert HTML menu to WP menu. I have div elements inside menu and that div elements are vertical line between li elements. I try do that with Walker class, but i couldn't find solution. 
This is code:

```
  <div class="nav-holder">
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>        
    <nav class="hamburger-menu">
      <ul>
        <div class="ver-line"></div>
        <li class="scroll-link">
          <a href="#biography">biografija</a>
        </li>
        <div class="ver-line"></div>
        <li class="scroll-link">
          <a href="#portfolio-content">portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <div class="ver-line"></div>
        <li class="scroll-link">
          <a href="#footer">kontakt</a>
        </li>
        <div class="ver-line"></div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- nav-holder -->
```

Comment: ``<ul>`` should only have ``<li>`` as child elements directly, not ``<div>`` or others. I think WP_Walker is the correct way to go. Your menu is relatively easy to create.

Comment: In addition to @Azametzin's comment, you can probably get this done with pseudo-elements on your `<li>`s. If you *have* to add them in the markup, add `aria-hidden="true"` if they don't have any semantic meaning!

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. This is vertical menu with vertical separator, I will try do that with html correction. Thank you for your help.